# Time complexity of a funcion with function*function in a loop

Tags: time-complexity

can you help me please to find the complexity of the following function:

```
proc (int n) 
{
 for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
 {
   x = g(n)+f(n) ;
   for (j=0 ; j<n ; j++)
    {
      y=h(j)*g(j) ;
    }
  }
return x+y ;
}
```

With f = O(n^2), g = O(n), h = Θ(log(n)).

The things I am not sure:

1. What is the complexity of "y = h(j) * g(j)", as to me n*log(n)?
2. Is there a difference in complexity if in the loop is "y = h(j) * g(j)" or just "h(j) * g(j)"?
3. Is it right, that the complexity of "x = g(n) + f(n)" is n + n^2?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help
center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). I think this question is better suited for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). You might want to search a bit there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Big O of x = O(n^2)
Big O of y = O(n log(n))
```

Now to compute the Big O of whole algorithm, we have to look at the inner most loop. And in this case, the inner most loop is contained in y = h(j) * g(j).
The Big O can be computed starting from the lowest and going towards up.
The Big O of x would be added not multiplied, because it is on the same level as of the inner for loop.

```
Big O = O(n log(n)) * O(n) * O(n) + O(n^2)
It can be written as:
Big O = O ((n log(n) * n * n) + (n * n^2))
Big O = O((n^3 log(n) + n^3)
Neglecting smaller terms would give us:
Big O = O(n^3 log(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Complexity of inner loop (sum of `h*g`)**

Since `h(j) = Θ(log(j))` and `g(j) = O(j)`, the complexity of `h(j).g(j)` is `O(j.log(j))`, that is `<= K.j.log(j)` for K > 0. Therefore the inner loop yields

```
   K.(1.log(1) + 2.log(2) + ... + (n-1).log(n-1))
<= K'.n^2.log(n)
```

For a well-chosen constant `K'` and the inner loop gives a complexity `O(n^2.log(n))`.

**Complexity of `g + f`**
`g = O(n)` and `f = O(n^2)` so the complexity of `f + g` is `O(n^2)`.

**Overall complexity**
**A:** Sum of `n` terms `O(n^2)` for `f+g` gives `O(n^3)`.
**B:** Sum of terms `j^2log(j)` for `0 <= j < n` gives `O(n^3.log(n))`.

Therefore the complexity of your method is `O(n^3.log(n))`.